# Get the last non-empty cell value in a column, based on a matching criteria on Google Sheets (ideally via script)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to get the last column's non-empty value based on a matching criteria, which is in a column right next to it. I have this working on via the formula below, but since I got like 10 columns, it takes too long to refresh and I was trying to find a way to have it working via app script.

This is a screenshot of the spreadsheet:
[image: Spreadsheet Screenshot]

The formula used currently:

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR((INDEX(F$7:F721;MATCH(MAX(IF(B$7:B721=$B722;A$7:A721;0));$A$7:$A721;0)));""))
```

Obs: It takes too long for the columns to load the results.

The formula I'm trying to use to see if this runs faster, but this one doesn't give me the right result:

```
=IF($B737="";"";(MAX(FILTER(C7:C736;$B$7:$B736=$B737))))
```

As for the scripting approach, I have tried a couple of code snipets, since I can't write one myself, but none of them got me to a solution.

Here's the link for an example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/133ugcf4LgdOMEv5LKVptjgR1OPKBtIs63BOYdeAFK_o/edit?usp=sharing

Any light is appreaciated.

Cheers,
Antonio Santos

Comment: Could you please share a sample sheet so solutions can be tested / demonstrated?  It can be done with Arrayformulas in a way that will not be slow to load for dozens of columns and thousands of rows.

Comment: Hello @MattKing!
I've just added the link to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Can you specify which columns you are talking about? Which column holds the array formula in question?

Comment: Hello @Aerials!
When I enter the Nº de Solicitação, the other columns should be automatically populated with the latest data entered for that Nº de Solicitação.
It's working already with =ArrayFormula(IFERROR((INDEX(F$7:F721;MATCH(MAX(IF(B$7:B721=$B722;A$7:A721;0));$A$7:$A721;0)));""))
...but it takes too long! Thanks for helping!

Comment: @AntonioSantos What is it that takes too long? It appears to be taking too long to get the solicitation numbers

Comment: Hello @Aerials!
Once I enter the Nº de Solicitação, then the spreadsheet loops through all cells where there are this formula and it being an arrayformula, it sweeps a wide range of cells, taking too long to load the latest info found in that column.

Comment: Can you share the apps script you have tried so far in Apps script?

Comment: Hi @Aerials,
No script tried so far.